# putting two overlapped boxes horizontally and vertically centred with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two boxes(divs) with known width and height, and want to put them in the body with following requirements. Let those boxes call `box1` and `box2`.

1) Both boxes should be vertically centered.

2) Both box should be placed in horizontally such that they overlap and `box1` remains 50% outside of the the `box2`.

3) `box1` + `box2` should be horizontally centred

I have written code for this and achieved 1st and 2nd but not able to do the 3rd one.

https://jsfiddle.net/02o2h6gp/1/

html code

```
<body>
    <div class="content">
       <div class="boxes-container">
         <div class="box1"></div>
         <div class="box2"></div>
       </div>
     </div>
</body>
```

CSS part

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(blue, white);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(blue, white);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(blue, white);
  background-image: linear-gradient(blue, white);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.content{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.boxes-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
  margin: auto;
}

.box1 {
  background: blue;
  box-shadow: 0 60px 80px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 271px;
  margin: auto;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

.box2 {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0 60px 80px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 740px;
  height: 586px;
  margin: auto;
  /*transform: translateX(-30%);*/
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Instead of translating box1 50% in x-axis, just translate box1 25% on x-axis and box -25% on x-axis. This way you will get equal space on both sides.
- Add align-content: center to .boxes-container.

```css
    html {
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(blue, white);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(blue, white);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(blue, white);
      background-image: linear-gradient(blue, white);
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .content{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .boxes-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-content: center;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .box1 {
      background: blue;
      box-shadow: 0 60px 80px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
      border-radius: 10px;
      width: 400px;
      height: 271px;
      margin: auto;
      transform: translateX(25%);
    }

    .box2 {
      background: #FFFFFF;
      box-shadow: 0 60px 80px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
      border-radius: 10px;
      width: 740px;
      height: 586px;
      margin: auto;
      /*transform: translateX(-30%);*/
      transform: translateX(-25%);
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="boxes-container">
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```